# AddOpenIdConnect is not called in ASP.NET Core 7 + Angular SPA project

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, single-page-application, .net-7.0

I am trying to implement BFF pattern with ASP.NET Core 7 + Angular and I need to register OpenId as authenticator and `AddOpenIdConnect` is not called in ASP.NET Core 7 SPA Angular project.

Create simple SPA app from ASP.NET Core with Angular.

This is the code of `Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json");
var config = configuration.Build();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(o =>
            {
                o.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                o.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                o.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                // Set the authority to your Auth0 domain
                options.Authority = $"https://{config.GetValue<string>("Auth0:Domain")}";

                // Configure the Auth0 Client ID and Client Secret
                options.ClientId = config.GetValue<string>("Auth0:ClientId");
                options.ClientSecret = config.GetValue<string>("Auth0:ClientSecret");

                // Set response type to code
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;

                options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.FormPost;

                // Configure the scope
                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                options.Scope.Add("read:weather");

                // Set the callback path, so Auth0 will call back to http://localhost:3000/callback
                // Also ensure that you have added the URL as an Allowed Callback URL in your Auth0 dashboard
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback");

                // Configure the Claims Issuer to be Auth0
                options.ClaimsIssuer = "Auth0";

                // This saves the tokens in the session cookie
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    // handle the logout redirection
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = (context) =>
                    {
                        var logoutUri = $"https://{config.GetValue<string>("Auth0:Domain")}/v2/logout?client_id={config.GetValue<string>("Auth0:ClientId")}";

                        var postLogoutUri = context.Properties.RedirectUri;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postLogoutUri))
                        {
                            if (postLogoutUri.StartsWith("/"))
                            {
                                // transform to absolute
                                var request = context.Request;
                                postLogoutUri = request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.PathBase + postLogoutUri;
                            }
                            logoutUri += $"&returnTo={Uri.EscapeDataString(postLogoutUri)}";
                        }
                        context.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);
                        context.HandleResponse();

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("audience", config.GetValue<string>("Auth0:ApiAudience"));
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
}

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Here's the content of `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Auth0": {
    "Domain": "<domain>",
    "ClientId": "<client id>",
    "ClientSecret": "<client secret>",
    "ApiAudience": "https://weatherforecast"
  }
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what is going on. The invocation of AddOpenIdConnect is being happened once the SPA hits API of the project in such setup. I was confused because in a just API project the  invocation of AddOpenIdConnect happens at the start of the project.